# Spring task scheduler first task execution time

Tags: spring, task, scheduled-tasks, scheduler, scheduledexecutorservice

After some research on spring task scheduler and task executor, I found below spring config would run myTask.run method every second.

```
<bean id="myTask" class="com.amazon.path.to.MyTask"/>

<task:scheduled-tasks scheduler="myScheduler">
    <!--run once every second-->
    <task:scheduled ref="myTask" method="run" fixed-rate="1000"/>
    <!--alternatively, run constantly, waiting one second after each run finished to start the next-->
    <!--<task:scheduled ref="myTask" method="run" fixed-delay="1000"/>-->
</task:scheduled-tasks>
<task:scheduler id="myScheduler" pool-size="1"/>
```

I want to know exactly when first invocation of the myTask.run occurs. It is mentioned nowhere in the docs. I referred [Spring XSD](http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task-3.0.xsd) for this. Also element **"task:scheduler"** creates instance of ThreadPoolTaskScheduler which from [Spring Doc](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/concurrent/ThreadPoolTaskScheduler.html) has method

```
scheduleAtFixedRate(Runnable task, Date startTime, long period)
```

which has startTime parameter. But in **XSD** reference above, there is no such attribute.

Comment: have you tried executing. If yes then what are your findings ?

Comment: You can control the first execution time using the `initial-delay` attribute, if you are willing/can use Spring 4

Comment: I haven't tried it yet because I do not want to depend upon current implementation details. If it is documented, I know it won't change in future and I can depend upon it safely. My use case is to warm cache during application startup. So I want a way to run this task just after all the beans have been initialized by spring container.

Comment: I am changing existing application which is using spring 3. I do not want to migrate to spring 4 because it will require testing a lot of other components being a production system for which I have no plan as of now.

Comment: From my test I came to conclusion that it executes it after all bean initializations. But I didn't found this documented any where.